# Acceder a los elementos hijos de un div con jquery

Tags: jquery

Tengo este código html:

```
<div class="tutor">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label>Nombre del Papá</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control nombreTutorVal">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label>Apellido Paterno del Papá</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control ape_paternoTutorVal">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label>Apellido Materno del Papá</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control ape_maternoTutorVal">
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label>Calle</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control calleVal">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label>Número</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control numeroVal">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label>Colonia</label>
      <select class="form-control id_coloniaVal">
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label>Código Postal</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control cpVal" onKeyPress="obtenerCP(event, $(this).parent());">
    </div>
   </div>  
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="tutor">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
       <label>Nombre de la Mamá</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control nombreTutorVal">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label>Apellido Paterno de la Mamá</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control ape_paternoTutorVal">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label>Apellido Materno de la Mamá</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control ape_maternoTutorVal">
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label>Calle</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control calleVal">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label>Número</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control numeroVal">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label>Colonia</label>
      <select class="form-control id_coloniaVal">
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label>Código Postal</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control cpVal" onKeyPress="obtenerCP(event, $(this).parent());">
    </div>
   </div>  
  </div>
```

En una base de datos tengo almacenadas las colonias con su respectivo código postal.

Como pueden ver tengo dos div con una clase llamada tutor, puesto que en cada div se colocarán los datos del padre y de la mamá.

Cuando en el campo *cpVal* se escriba un código postal y se de enter, en el select *id_coloniaVal* se mostrarán las colonias que tengan el código postal escrito. Pero obviamente si el codigo postal se escribió en el div del padre las colonias se deberán mostrar en su respectivo select al igual que si el código postal se escribe en el div de la mamá las colonias deberán mostrarse en su respectivo select.

Tengo este código JQuery:

```
function obtenerCP(e, tutor)
{
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
      if(code == 13){
       var cp = $(tutor).val();
       $(tutor).find('.calleVal').val(cp);
       return false;
      }
}
```

No logro hacer que funcione, como podría solucionar esto??

Answer (score 1):

Estas usando mal la funcion `find()`.  La variable `tutor` contiene el input, por lo tanto no hay elementos hijos que buscar dentro de el.  Lo que necesitas es buscar el elemento padre con la clase `tutor` mas cercano y utilizar `find()` en ese elemento.  Quedaria asi:

```
function obtenerCP(e, tutor)
{
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
      if(code == 13){
       var cp = $(tutor).val();
       $(tutor).parent(".tutor").find('.calleVal').val(cp);
       return false;
      }
}
```

Comment: No funciona, ni toma el valor del input que contiene la variable tutor ni encuentra el elemento .calleVal

Comment: En lugar de pasar `$(this).parent()` pasa solo `this`